How to I get all properties name of class and use them as a static variable in TypeScript?
In my project using TypeScript, I have a class like
class Car {
    model: string;
    year: number;
    price: string;

    constructor(model: string, year: number, price: string) {
        this.model = model;
        this.number = number;
        this.price = price;
    }
}

I have to read data from a json file. And the first thing, I need to check data from file has the same property of Car class.
I don't want to hash code fileData.hasOwnProperty('model'). My idea is similar to fileData.hasOwnProperty(Car.model). I want to make class properties as static recommend properties of Car class.
I would like to be able to reference any property in a class, such as Car.model, Car.year, or Car.price, ... in a way that returns the property name or similar information.
Do you have any idea for that?
Thank you so much
I tried like the following. But I don't think it's a good idea. Because in the future if I add more 5 properties, I also have to add 5 corresponding methods. And I don't want to add more methods in this case.
class Car {
    model: string;
    year: number;
    price: string;

    constructor(model: string, year: number, price: string) {
        this.model = model;
        this.number = number;
        this.price = price;
    }

    static model() {
        return 'model';
    }

    static year() {
        return 'year';
    }

    static price() {
        return 'price';
    }
}

I also try like the following. But It didn't recommend property name when I want to call Car.properties.model
class Car {
    model: string;
    year: number;
    price: string;

    constructor(model: string, year: number, price: string) {
        this.model = model;
        this.number = number;
        this.price = price;
    }

    static properties() {
        return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Car).map((property) => { property });
    }
}


"I don't want to hash code" - what?

I would suggest to add types and provide a scheme:
Playground
interface CarInterface{
    model: string;
    year: number;
    price: string;
}
type Types = {
    string: string,
    number: number,
    // add more
};
type FindKey<T extends object, U> = keyof {[K in keyof T as T[K] extends U ? K : never]: any};
type Scheme<T extends object> = {[K in keyof T]: FindKey<Types, T[K]>};

interface Car extends CarInterface{};
class Car implements Car{
    static scheme = {
        model:'string',
        year: 'number', 
        price:'string'
    } satisfies Scheme<Car>;

    constructor(data: Car) {
        for(const name in Car.scheme){
            if(!(name in data) || typeof (data as any)[name] !== (Car.scheme as any)[name]){
              throw new Error(`Data property "${name}" is missing or has invalid type`);
           }
        }
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}

const car = new Car({model: 'model', year: 2000, price: '$1000'});
const car2 = new Car({model: 2000, year: 2000, price: '$1000'} as any);


Just write an array literal in a static field:
class Car {
    model: string;
    year: number;
    price: string;

    constructor(model: string, year: number, price: string) {
        this.model = model;
        this.number = number;
        this.price = price;
    }

    static properties = ['model', 'number', 'price'] satisfies (keyof Car)[];
}

It is not possible to generate this list dynamically without instantiating a new Car.

Thanks everyone for your answer!
After careful consideration, I've decided to use class-validator and class-transformer for validation. This allows me to validate required properties and their types without manually specifying each property's name and type. The example here demonstrates how class-validator works, but in my project, I’ll use class-transformer to convert data with plainToInstance before running validations.
`
import { IsNotEmpty, IsString, IsInt } from "class-validator";
import "reflect-metadata";
export class Car {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    model: string;

    @IsInt()
    year: number;

    @IsString()
    price: string;
}

Call validate
validate(car).then(errors => {
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    throw new Error("Errors: " + errors.join("\n"));
  }
});

